# mongodb -- how to delete fields that have certain value

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I downloaded a lot of data from http://www.omdbapi.com/ and I stored the data in MongoDB.

The problem is, that I got a lot of fields with `"N/A"`, how can I delete all those fields, **without knowing** the fields names.

For example, from this document.

```
{
  "Title": "The Top 14 Perform",
  "Year": "2008",
  "Rated": "N/A",
  "Released": "02 Jul 2008",
  "Season": "4",
  "Episode": "12",
  "Runtime": "60 min",
  "Genre": "Game-Show, Music, Reality-TV",
  "Director": "Don Weiner",
  "Writer": "Simon Fuller (creator), Nigel Lythgoe (creator)",
  "Actors": "Joshua Allen, Stephen Boss, Cat Deeley, Matthew Dorame",
  "Plot": "Host Cat Deeley promised at the outset that the final 14 dancers will face some changes and the competition would get more difficult for the final seven couples...",
  "Language": "N/A",
  "Country": "N/A",
  "Awards": "N/A",
  "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxMjU0MTMxMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjY4Mjc3MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Metascore": "N/A",
  "imdbRating": "5.3",
  "imdbVotes": "13",
  "imdbID": "tt1234567",
  "seriesID": "tt0472023",
  "Type": "episode",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

I want to get this document.

```
{
  "Title": "The Top 14 Perform",
  "Year": "2008",
  "Released": "02 Jul 2008",
  "Season": "4",
  "Episode": "12",
  "Runtime": "60 min",
  "Genre": "Game-Show, Music, Reality-TV",
  "Director": "Don Weiner",
  "Writer": "Simon Fuller (creator), Nigel Lythgoe (creator)",
  "Actors": "Joshua Allen, Stephen Boss, Cat Deeley, Matthew Dorame",
  "Plot": "Host Cat Deeley promised at the outset that the final 14 dancers will face some changes and the competition would get more difficult for the final seven couples...",
  "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxMjU0MTMxMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjY4Mjc3MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "imdbRating": "5.3",
  "imdbVotes": "13",
  "imdbID": "tt1234567",
  "seriesID": "tt0472023",
  "Type": "episode",
  "Response": "True"
}
```

Comment: Are you actually wanting to modify the content in the document, so you'd have (for example) several entries with mismatched fields (say, 200 entries and only 150 have the 'Language' field) ? Or is this purely for display purposes

Comment: I'm actually want to modify the content in the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on the object and check for the value.

```
var o = {
  "Title": "The Top 14 Perform",
  "Year": "2008",
  "Rated": "N/A",
  "Released": "02 Jul 2008",
  "Season": "4",
  "Episode": "12",
  "Runtime": "60 min",
  "Genre": "Game-Show, Music, Reality-TV",
  "Director": "Don Weiner",
  "Writer": "Simon Fuller (creator), Nigel Lythgoe (creator)",
  "Actors": "Joshua Allen, Stephen Boss, Cat Deeley, Matthew Dorame",
  "Plot": "Host Cat Deeley promised at the outset that the final 14 dancers will face some changes and the competition would get more difficult for the final seven couples...",
  "Language": "N/A",
  "Country": "N/A",
  "Awards": "N/A",
  "Poster": "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTMxMjU0MTMxMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjY4Mjc3MQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
  "Metascore": "N/A",
  "imdbRating": "5.3",
  "imdbVotes": "13",
  "imdbID": "tt1234567",
  "seriesID": "tt0472023",
  "Type": "episode",
  "Response": "True"
} 

var toDelete = [];
for each (var prop in o) {
    if (o[prop] == "N/A") toDelete.push(prop);
}
for (var i=0; i < toDelete.length; i++) {
    delete o[toDelete[i]];
}
```